# php remove top level domain with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

i want to remove certain tld domain on my string, but i got a few problem.

```
$MyString = 'Amazon.com: pada port .com3 Dog Name Tags.com googl.com&trade; any.com™ on mys.co.uk® end.Commando is .commitment.com & communism.ca';
echo preg_replace('~\.(com|info|us|org|top|xyz|co\.in|co\.uk|ca|mobi)(?:[^a-z\d]|$)~i', '', $MyString );`
```

the code output is

```
Amazon pada port .com3 Dog Name Tagsgoogltrade; any on mys end.Commando is .commitment& communism
```

output that i want is

```
Amazon: pada port .com3 Dog Name Tags googl® any™ on mys®  end.Commando is .commitment & communism
```

Comment: `(?:[^a-z\d]|$)` will  match the extra chars and delete them, since you're not putting them into the replacement string.

Comment: if i remove (?:[^a-z\d]|$) => .com3 will removed too

Comment: what's to say that .com3 isn't a valid tld? icann is allowing pretty much everything, including kitchen sinks, as TLDs these days. you can't use a simple regex to filter what is essentially an eternally changing list of possible tlds

Comment: i'm sorry, I just want to remove certain tld that on pattern, not all tld

Comment: may be use preg_replace_callback ('~\.(com|info|us|org|top|xyz|co\.in|co\.uk|ca|mobi)(?:[^a-z\d]|$)~i', function($d){return substr($d[0],-1);}, $str);

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is common: you used a *consuming* non-capturing group `(?:[^a-z\d]|$)` that actually *eats up* a char other than an alphanumeric or end of string and it is thus missing in the `preg_replace` output.

Use a word boundary instead:

```
$MyString = 'Amazon.com: pada port .com3 Dog Name Tags.com googl.com® any.com™ on mys.co.uk® end.Commando is .commitment.com & communism.ca';
echo preg_replace('~\.(com|info|us|org|top|xyz|co\.in|co\.uk|ca|mobi)\b~i', '', $MyString );
```

See a [PHP online demo](https://ideone.com/ErgdAk)